# How to plot like this figure using LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

How can someone plot like this figure using LaTex? [image]

Comment: I would use asymptote. There is a nice tutorial, written by Charles Staats, here: http://math.uchicago.edu/~cstaats/Charles_Staats_III/Notes_and_papers_files/asymptote_tutorial.pdf Here is the main website for asymptote, which has a gallery of 3d graphs: http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3):

You could use the pgfplots package. More on that is explained in the guide  on this website: https://nl.sharelatex.com/learn/Pgfplots_package.

Below you see one of the examples that they treat: [image]

I hope this helps:)

Comment: Pgfplots is nice, but how can i draw the dashed lines?

Answer (score 1):

`Asymptote` version:

```
//
// localmax3d.asy
// 
// to get localmax3d.png, run
// asy -f png -render=4 localmax3d.asy
// 
import graph3;
size(200,0);
currentprojection=orthographic(camera=(-70,20,30),up=(0.4,-0.1,1),target=Z-Z,zoom=0.6);
triple fs1(pair t){
  real u=t.x, v=t.y;
  return (v*cos(2*pi*u),v*sin(2*pi*u),-4*v^2*cos(pi/2*v));
}
real eps=1e-4;
surface s1=surface(fs1,(eps,eps),(1,1),nu=12,nv=200,usplinetype=Spline);
draw(s1,paleblue+opacity(0.4),meshpen=nullpen,render(merge=true));
dot(fs1(0));
label("Local maximum",fs1(0),Z);
label("\noindent No global\\ maximum",fs1((0.25,0.75))+(0,0.5,0));
```

[image]